# Error while using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, dimensions

Getting

> ```
> Error "incorrect number of dimensions"
> ```

I have loaded in built dataframe `cars`

```
library(datasets)
data("cars")
lapply(cars,'[',1) #This will get the first row works fine
lapply(cars,'[',,1) #This should give me the first column but it gives me error incorrect dimensions
```

I have also tried converting the dataframe to list and it gives me correct row and fails to give column with same error .

Comment: Why are you using `lapply` here? `cars[1, ]` gives the first row, `cars[, 1]` gives the first column.

Comment: This is failing because `lapply` passes items of a list (for a data.frame, the columns) to a function (here `[`). Items passed to `lapply` after the function are passed as additional parameters to that function. Thus, passing one extra works, because `[` is passed two parameters: the list item (a vector of the column here), and `1` with which to subset it. Passing two extra parameters, a blank and `1`, tries to take that vector and subset it with a blank and `1`, which fails just like `c('a', 'b')[ , 1]` does.

Comment: Thanks Alistaire, that make sense. what I did not realise is what I'm trying to do will only work if a vector was passed in a list.